# Как получить массив listeners событий у элемента?

Tags: pure_js, javascript

Пример: 'onclick','onmouseup'. Ну и, соответственно, возможность их заменить.

Интересует НЕ jquery. Точнее, реализация на нативном JS или на самых ранних версиях библиотеки.

Смысл: есть элемент. Мы на него навешиваем новый эвент и делаем stopImmediatePropagation. Это понятно. Но задача в том, чтобы наш эвент при определенных условиях срабатывал ПЕРВЫМ. И прерывал исполнение остальных.

P.S. они листенеры. Я бы в жизни не догадался, что такое слушатели.

Comment: @knes Всегда лучше использовать русские слова для новых терминов.

Comment: С этим никто не спорит. Но так случилось, что русских компьютеров(почему-то никто не использует русское ЭВМ, а то и ЭВУ, хотя по сути, это синонимы) исчезающе малое количество, соответственно большая часть языков программирования так или иначе используют английский. Человек, работающий с языком видит привычное слово "listener", которое входит в состав названия функций работы с событиями: addEventListener(), например. Чтобы перевести это на русский надо в том числе поменять порядок слов. А в этом случае, название меняется до неузнаваемости...

Comment: Посмотрите [кроссбраузерное навешивание событий][1] - класс, облегчающий работу с событиями. На его основе можно написать нужный вам вариант.

[1]:http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/crossbrowser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы прерывал исполнение остальных достаточно например:

```
    element = document.getElementById("element");
    element.onclick = functionName;
    //теперь допустим что после отработки функции functionName
    //нам надо изменить обработчик
    function functionName() {
        //тут чета делаем
        this.onclick = anotherFunction; //цепляем новый обработчик
        // ну и естественно мы можем накинуть какой-то обработчик, или удалить
        // в теле этой же функции
    }
```

О веселом закончили, теперь о грустном - получить все обработчики элемента стандартными средствами языка невозможно, как вариант написать свою функцию, но не уверен что после ознакомления с этим кодом это пригодится.
Если же это все равно будет необходимо - способ получения всех обработчиком придется написать самому.

PS:надеюсь правильно понял задачу.

Comment: Вы очень хороший пример привели. У вас событие онклик. Если где-то висит обработчик onmousedown, то онклик сработает ПОСЛЕ обработчика нажатия на мышку.
И таких примеров много: нажатие на кнопки клавиатуры, клик в движении и прочее, когда приходится исполнять обработчики для нескольких "одновременных".
Вот задача поменять приоритет исполнения, не лазая глубоко.  
Джиквери, к слову, использует невполне честный метод: она при навешивании события запихивает в массив-подсказку что за событие было прикреплено.  
Иными словами, список событий и их приоритет - ридонли. Это печально.

Comment: кстати с тех пор как начал понимать все прелести ООП в JavaScript на JQuery пишу только если от меня это требуют :)